# how to get the bundle product prices in the Magento 2 for specific customer group?

Tags: magento2, price, customer-group, bundle-product

***how to get the bundle product prices (Maximum & Minimum) in the Magento 2 for customer group and tax as well?***

I tried various functions in the Magento's default code but did not get the exact output with functions.

Comment: FYI, I tried this function:
list($minimalPrice, $maximalPrice) = $item->getPriceModel()->getTotalPrices($item, null, false, false);

Comment: Is it for current customer's group or some other specified group?

Comment: Have you find solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code in order to fetch the bundle product price range (maximum and minimum price)

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$product = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load(your_product_Id);
$bundleObj=$product->getPriceInfo()->getPrice('final_price');
echo $bundleObj->getMinimalPrice();// For min price
echo $bundleObj->getMaximalPrice(); // for max price
```

For Tier price for specific customer group, try following way:

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository,
    \Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductTierPriceInterfaceFactory $priceFactory,
    \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $config,
    \Magento\Customer\Api\GroupManagementInterface $groupManagement
) {
    $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
    $this->priceFactory = $priceFactory;
    $this->config = $config;
    $this->groupManagement = $groupManagement;

}
```

And then:

```
$sku = '24-MB01';
$customerGroupId = 1;
$product = $this->productRepository->get($sku, ['edit_mode' => true]);

$priceKey = 'website_price';
$value = $this->config->getValue('catalog/price/scope', \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_WEBSITE);
if ($value == 0) {
    $priceKey = 'price';
}

$cgi = ($customerGroupId === 'all'
    ? $this->groupManagement->getAllCustomersGroup()->getId()
    : $customerGroupId);

$prices = [];
foreach ($product->getData('tier_price') as $price) {
    if ((is_numeric($customerGroupId) && intval($price['cust_group']) === intval($customerGroupId))
        || ($customerGroupId === 'all' && $price['all_groups'])
    ) {
        /** @var \Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductTierPriceInterface $tierPrice */
        $tierPrice = $this->priceFactory->create();
        $tierPrice->setValue($price[$priceKey])
            ->setQty($price['price_qty'])
            ->setCustomerGroupId($cgi);
        $prices[] = $tierPrice->getValue();
    }
}
echo '<pre>';print_r($prices);
```

**I hope this will help**